# HTML5 Canvas Resize - possible to control or predict memory issues?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

In my web app I'm allowing the user to take a photo (that will be uploaded to a server), and then resizing:

```js
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    canvas.width = newWidth;
    canvas.height = newHeight;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context!.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    finalDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
```

*newWidth* and *newHeight* are set so that the longest edge is not greater than 1920.

Most of the time the above works well, but sometimes the browser reports memory issues and crashes - I assume the chances are greater on a device with a high resolution camera. Is there a way I can be more in control in terms of memory management, to ensure that this does not crash?